# Accessing a struct inside an enum

Tags: struct, enums, rust

How do I access field `c` inside `struct` of type `B_` inside `enum` of type `A` in this case?

```
enum A {
    B(B_),
    D(D_)
}

enum D_ { D_1, D_2 }

struct B_ {
    c: Vec<i32>,
}
```

Obvious stuff like this doesn't work:

```
let y = A::B;
y.c = Vec::new();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the first problem is that what you really want is `y` to be of type `A`, so it cannot have a field named `c` in the first place. `y` can be `A::B` or `A::D`. Only if `y` is an `A::B` variant, then you can get the `B_` object inside the variant and then get the `c`.

The second problem in your code is that you are not initializing `y` to be an `A::B` variant. The expression `A::B` is of type `fn(B_) -> A {A::B}` which is a kind of constructor function (automagically generated by the compiler) for `A` enums.

The following code initialize `y` correctly and get `c`:

```
enum A {
    B(B_),
    D(D_)
}

enum D_ { D_1, D_2 }

struct B_ {
    c: Vec<i32>,
}

fn main() {
    let y = A::B( B_ { c : Vec::new() });

    // Check if y is an A::B, so we can get the B_ object inside
    // by deconstruction. Then we can get c.
    if let A::B(b_) = y {
        println!("{:?}", b_.c);
    }
}
```

Maybe you thought that `A::B` is a kind of `B` type defined "inside" `A`, which is not how enums work is Rust.